# NS-3 VANET: How to implement simple intersection scenario?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I am using NS-3 to implement a simple FIFO intersection scenario in DSRC-based VANETs. Since I am new to NS-3, I would appreciate any detailed guide on how to make the code.

As for this scenario, the first question might be how to build intersection/ road and coordinates? Then I might be needing to generate road traffic on each of 4 queues and let them go through the intersection as FIFO. Finally some parameters such as intersection throughput (per minute/hour) needs to be measured. I assume I can apply a trace file from SUMU/VISSIM.

I think this simple scenario may be helpful as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use trace files generated by SUMO. Simply generate them in 'ns2' format that ns-3 can interpret/parse. How to generate such trace files is explained in the SUMO documentation.

See https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.14/models/html/mobility.html#ns-2-mobilityhelper

Comment: Thanks. Can ns-2-mobilityhelper parse trace files created by Vissim ?